# Shouldn’t “art” be “is” in “Our Father who art in heaven”?

Tags: verb-agreement, relative-clauses, early-modern-english, relative-pronouns, grammatical-person

The [Lord’s Prayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord's_Prayer) begins in English:

> **Our Father who art in heaven**, 
> hallowed be Thy name, 
> Thy kingdom come,
>  Thy will be done
>  on earth as it is in heaven.

Shouldn’t it be *who is* there, not *who art*?  You would have said *thou art* and *he is* at the time this was written. See [the Wikipedia article on *Thou*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou) for example.

Comment: It wasn't originally written in English. And arguably, this isn't - certainly not the English of today.

Comment: In order to understand it better you can think "you" before "art". Compare German: Vater unser, der du bist im Himmel ... Word for word: Father our, who thou art in heaven ...

Comment: Related: [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical) and [It is I who am at fault](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68919/it-is-i-who-am-at-fault).

Comment: Perhaps if it had been “O Father, who art in heaven”, that would have been more clearly the person addressed.  But it didn’t start out that way in the original.

Comment: No, it's fine because his father's name is Art(hur).   Or maybe Harold, as in "our father who, Art, in heaven, Harold be thy name"

Comment: @CarlWitthof No. It ends ... Hello what's your name?

Comment: You is a naughty person.

Comment: It is the second-person singular conjugation used in Early Modern English—that of Shakespeare and the King James Bible, e.g. "Thou art a scurvy knave." In this case, it is the form used in direct address (which is how it's used in the Lord's Prayer).

Comment: @tchrist : O or ὦ, the default determiner for a vocative, is here displaced by ἡμῶν / Our, but since the noun πατήρ (father) has the specifically vocative inflected form πάτερ here, the Greek makes its vocative character unmistakable, in a way the English cannot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Our Father who art in heaven, hallowed be Thy (your) Name," is the rest of that sentence.

By saying "Our Father... Thy..." you are addressing God personally, making that the second person singular (you are). (First person singular: I am. Third person singular: he/she/it is.) "Our Father" is not speaking *about* God; it is speaking *to* God. (It is like saying, *Hey, Dad,* you, up there. Blessed be *your* name.)

If it were about *Him*, it would certainly be *He is*. From the same book which states *Our Father, who art in heaven*:

> For the Lord *is* our judge, the Lord *is* our lawgiver, the Lord *is* our king; he will save us. - Isaiah 33:22

Quoting your source:

> When thou is the grammatical subject of a finite verb in the indicative mood, the verb form ends on t... (e.g., "thou goest"; "thou dost"), but in some cases just -t (e.g., "thou art"; "thou shalt")

and

> Originally, thou was simply the singular counterpart to the plural pronoun ye... thou was later used to express intimacy...

and

> The familiar form is used when speaking to God... (an "informal" singular form of the second person in modern speech.)

Comment: The "who" seems misplaced for this explanation to be correct. It seems who should instead be thou.

Comment: @Lembik Not in the Early Modern English of your version. The [modern translation](http://www.lords-prayer-words.com/) uses neither.

Comment: @Lembik - When someone asks you, "Who *are* you? Do you have any question that they are talking to you? What does the word *who* have to do with it? It is akin to saying *which*. The extended quote is "After this manner therefore pray ye: Our Father which art in heaven, Hallowed be thy name," or "“Pray, then, in this way:
Our Father who art in heaven, Hallowed be Thy name." There is no question that it is a prayer *to* God.

Comment: @Lembik Try imagining a “you” (or “thou”) before the whole thing: “You, our Father, who are in Heaven” is perfectly grammatical even in Modern English. 400 years ago when the KJV was made, that initial “you” was not necessary for the construction to be idiomatic; nowadays it is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think an implicit "thou" is the most plausible answer so far.  Perhaps add it as an answer?

Comment: @Andrew Leach **The** _modern translation_ ?

Comment: I find this logic weird. Anything in support?

Comment: @Kris, if you tell me (please) which part of my reasoning is weird, maybe I can clarify or cite sources.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry: the standard inter-denominational modern translation by ICEL.

Comment: In [Italian](http://www.prayer.su/italian/common/) we say (translated): Our father, (who/that) **you are** in heaven, blessed is **your** Name, **Your** kingdom come, **Your** will be done etc...

Comment: Your italicized instances of the insert ***is*** amuse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That may not be clear to all readers. [In the modern Italian version](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padre_nostro#Traduzione_italiana_.28versione_in_uso_nella_liturgia_cattolica.29), you use 2nd-person **informal “you”** forms (*tu*), not **formal “you”** forms (*Lei*), which are grammatically 3rd-person in modern Italian. (So more like Spanish’s *tu/Usted* distinction than French’s *tu/vous* one in terms of formal concordance.)

Comment: I am happy with an implicit "thou" as an explanation. However I really don't understand those who claim that an equivalent "Peter, who are in the living room, I hope you are well." as standard English.

Comment: Note “I who am your father”, “You who are my father”, “Thou who art my father”; but compare “O Peter&Paul&Mary, you who are in the living room” versus “That Judas who is the living room”.  Note how the last pair differ from each other: an appositive to a vocative in the former but not the latter. “I, Thomas, am ready to leave.” “We people are ready to leave.” You just don’t have much inflection in English, so you are unused to a more inflected version.

Comment: @Lembik, Imagine children speaking reverentially to their father: *Dear Father, you *who* **are** so good to us, may you be honored by us always.* Is there any verb which can be substituted for **are**? No. *You who is?* (No.) You who *am*? (No.) *You who are so good to us* say his children.

Comment: @medica Right.  In all these explanations we need to insert the word "you".

Comment: @Lembik - I don't mean to be a bulldog, but you *don't* need to insert a *you*. The *you* is carried by the verb *are*, or, in the original question, the *art*.

Comment: @anongoodnurse This is about three years late, but Lembik is right here: in current-day English, we _do_ need to insert an explicit pronoun, as indeed you did in your example. “Dear Father, who are so good to us” is exceedingly awkward as normal English now and highly marked as archaicising. If the Bible were first translated now and the relative clause kept, it would no doubt read, “Our Father, _you_ who are in Heaven” as well, with the pronoun.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Hmm, you're right. Thanks! Better late than never in this case. I actually think Terdon's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 7):

The main issue here is that the [original Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Prayer#Greek_and_Latin_versions) uses a form that does not exist in English. The relevant portion of the Greek text reads:

> Πάτερ ἡμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς·

Translated directly, word for word, that is:

> Father ours the one in the heavens.

Or, to make it closer to actual English:

> Our Father, in the heavens.

The *ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς* has no direct equivalent form in English, it literally means *the one in the heavens*. Well, the *sky* actually, but some poetic license is assumed. The main point is that there is no verb there, the text is not saying "who *is* in heaven" but "the one in heaven".

As @anongoodnurse [already pointed out](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/171245/25030), the prayer addresses God in the second person, therefore, the *art* is quite correct and the sentence could be rephrased to:

> Our father, *thou* who art in heaven, hallowed be *thy* name.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. "Father ours the one in the heavens." is particularly helpful.

Comment: It must be really nice to know Greek. I wish I did, but I chose Latin instead. +1

Comment: @anongoodnurse well, it does help if one happens to *be* Greek :) In this particular case, the sentence is understandable to any modern Greek speaker. I know no more Ancient Greek than you do, and quite possibly less.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the sentence is an invocation or an address to, not a statement about God:

Compare  "Our Father, who art in heaven, hallowed be thy name" with "Our father, who's in Paris at the moment, is a really nice guy.

Also compare "I, who am the boss here, am going to fire you." "I who is the boss here" is just wrong. Same principle.

The seeminly odd grammar implies something like: "Our Father - the one in heaven that is, not some earthly guy - may your name be made holy"

The oddness is probably heightened though because "thou/who art" is archaic so it stands out.

Compare a sentence like this: "You, who are the love of my life, have given me so much happiness!" Once again, same thing happening.

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself said: "Thou art". "Our Father" etc. is a title by which the speaker is addressing god. This is confirmed by the next section, "hallowed be Thy name", which is essentially a parenthetical addition to that title.

So it really is self-consistent, though not a form we're used to hearing these days and further obscured by being poetic phrasing rather than simple prose.

(Actually, I'd expect a modern reader to have more trouble with the imperative use of "come" and "be done" later in that sentence.)

Comment: Those aren’t imperatives; they’re present subjunctives. One does not command the Lord.  Not that there is any morphological difference from an infinitive in either case.

Comment: Hm. Possibly. (I don't think it was commanding the Lord but asserting that these shall/must occur, which may be what drew me off track.)

Comment: It is *definitely* the subjunctive. Hallowed *be* Thy name, not *is*. Imperative: *Hallow Thy name!* or *Hallow His name, all ye peoples...*. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The passage is written in second person, addressing God as Father (*Pater* in the Greek). Second person required the verb *are*, not *is*. The agreement is in person rather than number.The Greek text actually has no verb in the adjective phrase rendered "Which art in heaven." The Greek did not need *art* or *are* for the sense to be clear regarding where the verse was locating God. The Latin Vulgate placed the verb (*es*)in the phrase. The Authorized Version of the Bible (the 1611 King James Version) was an English translation of the Vulgate, and so carried the verb into that revered version. For second person formal address the verb *art* was used. Most modern translations keep the verb. At least one does not-- The Good News Translation, 2nd Edition, simply says, "Our Father in heaven."

Comment: Pater is Latin. And other translations simply say, "Father in heaven...."

Comment: @medica _pater_ (πατήρ) is actually [Greek for _father_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%81#Ancient_Greek) and the original text of this prayer [was indeed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Prayer) written in Greek so the Latin version of _Pater_ is irrelevant. Garry is also quite correct about the Greek version not having a verb, it basically says _Our father, the one in heaven_ or _he who is in heaven_ if you prefer.