# Don't VS Doesn't

Tags: grammar

I'd like to ask a question regarding proper grammar in this case.

In a scenario where I say "It is you who doesn't know what you are talking about", is that grammatically correct or should it be "It is you who don't know" in regards to "you" instead?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: This was answered in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68919/it-is-i-who-am-at-fault), which was closed as a duplicate of a question that doesn't answer this question. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: People say *"It is I who am"* (classical grammar) and *"It is me who is"* (new-fangled grammatical innovation looked down upon by pedants). Since *you* is the same in both the subjective and an objective cases, shouldn't both *is* and *are* be considered correct? (Only for singular *you*, of course.)

Comment: The frequency of *is* certainly has increased over the past few decades. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+you+who+are%2CIt+is+you+who+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20you%20who%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20you%20who%20is%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: The reason for the _doesn't_ is that the subject of the relative clause is not _you_ (which is in the clause above), but _who_. And _who_ almost always appears as third person, and therefore for many people is marked as third person and takes _doesn't_. Note that it's third person singular, not plural (which would be _don't_, like _you_), derived from the singular _you_; but for those people it's still third person. This is the kind of situation that either changes the rule or throws up some frozen idioms  that set a new pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

> It is you who don't know

As you correctly say, the pronoun "you" takes the "do" form of the verb.  "Does" is the third-person ("he does...").  "You do not know" -> "You don't know" -> "You who don't know".