# Which sentence is correct? They or them?

Tags: sentence

> "It was them who cleaned the classroom."

or

> "It was they who cleaned the classroom?"

Comment: [*Who Killed Cock Robin?*](http://tomclarkblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/who-killed-cock-robin-mystery.html) *Not I*, said the sparrow. *Not **me***, said the grammarian.

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: The point is grammarians tell us we *should* say ***Not I***, but in practice the vast majority of native speakers tend to ignore that anyway. Unfortunately, the standard nursery rhyme has the sparrow saying it "correctly", so what I wrote isn't strictly correct (if the sparrow had been a normal Anglophonic talking bird today, he's have said ***Not me!***, and it would be the *grammarian* correcting him to ***Not I!***).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Who wants ice-cream?" — Should I say "(not) I" or "(not) me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me)

Comment: _It was they cleaned the classroom_.

Comment: The supposed "duplicate" suggested by FumbleFingers is very remotely related to this question. For a more relevant post, see Barrie England's answer here, but keep in mind that it's not obvious that you would get the same results for the third-person singular pronoun as for the first-person singular pronoun: [It is I who am at fault?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68919/it-is-i-who-am-at-fault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, the second one (It is they) is correct. According to [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/it-is-i-versus-it-is-me):

> ... when a pronoun follows a linking verb, such as "is," the pronoun should be in the subject case.

Later on, she elaborates on the subject by saying:

> Linking verbs are words like "is," "was," "were," "appear," and "seem," which don't describe an action so much as describe a state of being. When pronouns follow these non-action verbs, you use the subject pronouns such as "I," "she," "he," "they," and "we."

She also gives us a few examples:

> Who called Jodie? It was he.
>
> Who told you about it? It was I.
>
> Who had the phone conversation? It must have been they.
>
> Who cares? It is we.

Answer (score 0):

"It was them who cleaned the classroom."

Same as: We wouldn't want them to think we were doing anything immoral.
He bent over, picked up her clothes and tossed them to her.
Why had he hidden them - and why had he decided to reveal them?